# Acumatica import from spreadsheet

Tags: acumatica

I am trying to find a way to import data from a spreadsheet(excel) to fill all the fields on a particular screen?

I have data for Sales Order Screen in an excel spreadsheet and want to import the data to acumatica without manually entering it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you have a chance to check Acumatica [Import and Export Scenarios](https://help.acumatica.com/?ScreenId=ShowWiki&pageid=857321f7-0939-42ab-9421-fb85566b6d24)? A very good source of information on Import and Export Scenarios is the I100 training course available on [Acumatica University](https://acumatica.litmos.com/) and [Acumatica Open University](http://acumaticaopenuniversity.com/courses/integration/i100-integration-scenarios/)